# What if the characteristic polinomials is equal to 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I am sure i did something wrong but what happen if i get p($x$)$
=0$ ?

Every value of "x" will be an eigenvalue for A...   ...thats obviusly not possible in my $R^3$ space.

Comment: Is it possible to see the example?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  &1 \\ 
0 &-2  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It indeed has zero determinant, but its characteristic polynomial should be a nonzero cubic polynomial

Comment: Dumb thing of the day.

Comment: no problem! just enjoy the site of numbers before they disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is never $0$, since it always contains a term of degree $3$. In your case the characteristic polynomial is $-x^3-2x^2$

Comment: This seems to be a good candidate fo the dumb question contest...   ...sorry guys. Thaks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional space (or of an $n\times n$ matrix) is by construction a *monic* polynomial of degree$~n$. The zero polynomial is not monic, so it can never be a characteristic polynomial (not even for $n=0$, for which the characteristic polynomial is the constant polynomial $1$). On the other hand every monic polynomial can occur as a characteristic polynomial (for instance of its own companion matrix).

So to answer the question, "pigs fly".